# Python iterations

Tags: python

Has anybody any idea why this code fails to run smooth? It seems not to like iterations with the yield keyword:
I am trying to mine all the numbers from any level of lists or dicts ( especially interested in lists ).
At the second iteration it finds [2,3] but fails to print 2 and 3 one after other...Imagine also that I could have many levels of lists.

```
def digIn( x ):
    try:
        if isDict(x) or isList(x):
            print "X:", x
            for each in x:
                print "each:", each
                if isDict(each) or isList(each):
                    digIn(each)
                else:
                    yield each
        else:
            yield x
    except Exception,ex:
        print ex

print "STARTING OVER"
for i in digIn( [1,[2,3]] ):
    print i
```

Comment: Since it's night, and we are discussing it...how would you see this version : http://pastebin.com/nZ2b4LUP   ?

Comment: what's the difference of digIn() with a run-on-the-mill flatten?

Comment: Hi, long time! well, I mean that the function digIn seems to be very similar to a flatten operation. But I see you also digIn in dictionaries so maybe not.

Comment: In deed. It is supposed to go under a heavy load of dicts and lists inside of which can exist an infinite number of dicts, lists, and plain variables. From all this "ecosystem", I want eventually the data. So it has to identify what kind of data, and of course recursively iterate inside it.

Answer (score 1):

You should 're-yield' the generator to iterate through all list elements recursively.

```
if isDict(each) or isList(each):
     for elem in digIn(each):
         yield elem
else:
     yield each
```

Answer (score 1):

`digIn(each)` is incorrect. You must iterate over it, and yield each value in turn.

Answer (score 1):

When you recursively call `digIn` the inner yields don't cause values to be yielded from the outer call. Instead the recursive `digIn` is returning a generator and then you are silently discarding that generator and losing the inner items.

You need to explicitly yield the results from the recursive call.

```
if isDict(each) or isList(each):
    for innerItem in digIn(each):
        yield innerItem
else:
    yield each
```